# How can I download the examples from twitter bootstrap website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a tutorial in which the authors says to download the "Basic Marketing website" template from the twitter bootstrap website: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

I see the example in the example section, but I can't figure out how can I download it. The author says it will be a hero.html file.

Can you please help me here? Thanks.

Comment: If you download the example "as-is" using your browser's "Safe Page" feature, remember to grab the matching `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/[version]/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map` so you can see where in the SCSS things are defined.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You will find it in the full download at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master

The examples are in the /site/content/docs/[version]/examples folder

Comment: the above link seems no more providing the bootstrap example files. as checked on 27 March, 2014.

Comment: @ravk Aha, correct. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: On Github, mentioned above, I found the example files here: `bootstrap/site/content/docs/4.3/examples/`

Answer (score 2):

**The new updated path is as mentioned below:**

[The examples are in /docs/examples/ in a full download of the Bootstrap source code](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.1.1.zip)

Thanks @cvrebert (http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13196) for providing the new path.