# Where do I start in terms of creating a proper folder structure for an HTML/CSS/Javascript site to be built using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Git, I cloned the latest release of Twitter Bootstrap using:

git clone git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git

I'm trying to create an html/ css site using Bootstrap and from this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180420, I've noticed that all the HTML and CSS docs are both ***included*** and ***pre-compiled*** with the download:

SO, if I wanted to create an **HTML site** using some or all aspects from the examples,  is it just as simple as copy and pasting different html/CSS/Javascript code from the examples **included** in the download from these folders?

For example, if I wanted to create a new site and include **navbar.html**, **carousel.js**, and other html and css code, what are the best practices for creating the folder structure for making that work (and using direct html/css code from the examples)?

Where do I start in terms of creating a proper folder structure for an HTML/CSS/Javascript site to be built using Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: http://ollomedia.com/using-twitter-bootstrap-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I do it.

Add the css at the top, jquery at the bottom... add the bootstrap css before your custom css files and add the jquery js file (if using) before your own custom js..

Make sure you have jquery library loaded.

As an example, you may want to look at http://media.serviceportal.com.au/service05/igasummer2013.do

so basically

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link href="assests/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assests/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="assests/js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
       <link href="assests/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
       <link href="assests/css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<link href="assests/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
................................
................................
................................

</div>
<script src="assests/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assests/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assests/js/custom.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```